# How to create my own Set Class, with new functionalities

Tags: java, class, collections, set

So I want to make a class named SortIntsSet, which is basically a Set, but with different implementations. For example, I want to have two methods one for add, which only adds absolute values to the set, and second get size.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Set;

public class SortIntsSet {

private Set<Integer> mySet;
private int size;

public SortIntsSet() {
    mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
}

public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

public void add(int i) {
    mySet.add(Math.abs(i));
}}
```

The problem arises here: when i create an instance of it in the main class like this:

```
Set<Integer> myset = new SortIntsSet();
```

It gives me an error saying: Required type Set, Provided myset

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the interface `Set`

```
public class SortIntsSet implements Set<Integer>
```

Comment: Yes, but then i have to implement all the methods of Set. And i only want to have two methods add and size nothing more.

Comment: You can olso extends `HashSet` and override only methods that you want to change. Bau you can not assign a class to interface `Set`  which is not implementing this interface